# How do I test if deinit was called properly?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my unit test:

```
    func testDeinit() {
        let view = DocumentsView(theme: MockTheme())
        let viewModel = DocumentsViewModelMock()
        let delegate = DocumentsViewControllerDelegateMock()
        var controller: DocumentsViewController? = DocumentsViewController(view: view, viewModel: viewModel, delegate: delegate)
        controller?.viewDidLoad()
        let expectation = self.expectation(description: "")
        XCTAssertFalse(delegate.documentViewControllerDeinitializedWasCalled)
        controller = nil
        XCTAssertTrue(delegate.documentViewControllerDeinitializedWasCalled)
    }
```

`deinit` looks like this:

```
deinit {
    delegate?.documentViewControllerDeinitialized()
}
```

and my delegate:

```
class DocumentsViewControllerDelegateMock: DocumentsViewControllerDelegate {
    var documentViewControllerDeinitializedWasCalled = false
    func documentViewControllerDeinitialized() {
        documentViewControllerDeinitializedWasCalled = true
    }
}
```

My init of `DocumentsViewController`.

```
    private weak var delegate: DocumentsViewControllerDelegate?
    // MARK: - Initialization
    init(view: DocumentsView, viewModel: DocumentsViewModelable, delegate: DocumentsViewControllerDelegate) {
        self.mainView = view
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
```

above unit test fails. Why?

The case is because deinit is called **AFTER** XCTAssertTrue is checked. How to do it async way?

Comment: Could it be that your controller has a strong reference to its delegate property and that the test also has a strong reference so that controller isn't deallocated until the test has finished?

Comment: No, there is a weak reference.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is a bad test.

You're basically testing to see if what's in your `deinit` is called if the object is deallocated. That's not something you test. Apple's Swift designers should test that.

Instead do two other tests.

1. Test to see if after you do `controller = nil`, that the controller is deallocated or not. You can just do an `XCTAssertNil`. The trick is to get a `weak` reference to the controller so you can pass that to the assert
2. Test what's inside the `deinit` method in an isolated matter. In
   your case that would be a manual trigger of
   `delegate?.documentViewControllerDeinitialized()` +
   `XCTAssertTrue(delegate.documentViewControllerDeinitializedWasCalled)`

Doing it this way you'd also avoid mocking the `DocumentsViewControllerDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the `delegate` from the unit test deallocates right after you initialize the `DocumentsViewController`. That's because there are no more strong references to the delegate afterwards, there's only a `weak` one in the controller. And due to this, the controller no longer has a delegate to call upon deinit.

Try prolonging the life of the delegate, e.g. by doing a dummy assert on it (e.g. `XCTAssertEquals(controller.delegate, delegate)`.